# Loading a custom kernel causes VM to constantly reboot

Tags: c++, assembly, operating-system, osdev, low-level

I am working on a custom 32-bit OS, and i have coded a bare bones bootloader. I am trying to make it load a simple kernel that puts a char onto the screen, however, instead of getting the char i get a triple fault (maybe?)

I've tried increasing the number of sectors read, the number of 'db 0's in my extended program, tampering with the compilation script...

Nothing, however, my OS also prints the letter 'H' if it succeeds to read the disk, and sometimes when I increase the number of sectors to something exponential, the vm doesn't restart, but the disk isn't read successfully.

Github: https://github.com/Nutty000/Broken-OS

Comment: Get qemu or bochs (classic emulators for osdev) and learn to use the debugger.

Comment: Debugger shows absolutely nothing that can help me

Comment: It doesn't show why the VM restarts?

Comment: Have you implemented exception handlers? I also doubt the debugger doesn't show anything useful; have you tried emitting breakpoints in your code to see where it crashes?

Comment: It crashes right after switching to Protected mode. I have no idea how to write fault handlers in assembly

Comment: Bochs's built-in debugger should show the cause of a triple-fault, and let you single-step instructions during the transition to protected mode.  (It knows about segmentation, unlike GDB attached to QEMU).  It can also dump the GDT for you so you can see if you put the bits in the right place.  If a debugger isn't showing you useful info, your problem is learning to use it more effectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"BROKEN-OS", you say?

Your GitHub *ldr.asm* file has many errors.
The Boot Sector and BPB Structure uses all the wrong data sizes! No wonder your VM gets all confused.

```
                                            should be
                                            ---------  
OEMIdentifier               db "POSv0.10"
BytesPerSector              dd 512            DW
SectorsPerCluster           db 1
ReservedSectors             db 32             DW
NumberOfFATs                db 2
NUmberOfRootDirEntries      db 224            DW
NumberOfSectors             dd 2880           DW
MediaDescriptorType         db 0xf0
SectorsPerFAT               db 9              DW
SectorsPerTrack             db 18             DW
NumberOfSides               db 2              DW
HiddenSectors               db 0              DD
LargeSectorCount            db 0              DD

DriveNumber             db 0x00
                        db 0
Signature               db 0x29
VolumeID                db 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
VolumeLabel             db "POSBOOTDSK "
SystemIdentifier        db "FAT12   "
```

---

> ```
> jmp short mbrcodestart
> ```

This short jump is encoded with **2** bytes, but the above mentioned structure must begin at offset 3 in your bootsector. You need to pad with a `nop` instruction, or force a `near` (non-short) jmp.

```
jmp short mbrcodestart
nop
```

---

The fact of storing a capital "H" as the first byte of your [ExtendedSpace] that you later jump to was a bad idea, but luckily for you that will not pose a problem as that particular encoding 72 happens to correspond to a valid one-byte instruction `dec ax`.

---

There's also:

- not setting up the segment registers yourself
- not setting up a stack in a safe place where the additional sectors can't overwrite it
- ignoring the `BH` and `BL` parameters of the BIOS.Teletype call
- not inspecting the carry flag that you get from the `int 13h` call
- reading many sectors at once instead of the more reliable method of using a loop of reading individual sectors.  (Some real-world BIOSes are somewhat broken; using only the simplest functionality will let your bootloader work even on such machines.  See also [Michael Petch's general tips for bootloaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32701854/boot-loader-doesnt-jump-to-kernel-code/32705076#32705076).)
- ...

All of this happens even before diving into protected mode. First make sure the real mode part works fine before attempting to go further.

There are many good answers on this forum that deal with these issues:

[Bootloader doesn't jump to kernel code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32701854/boot-loader-doesnt-jump-to-kernel-code/32705076#32705076)

[My OS is showing weird characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71352633/my-operating-system-is-showing-weird-characters/71365693?r=SearchResults&s=11%7C0.0000#71365693)

Your current *ldr.asm* for reference:

```
[org 0x7c00]

jmp short mbrcodestart

OEMIdentifier               db "POSv0.10"
BytesPerSector              dd 512
SectorsPerCluster           db 1
ReservedSectors             db 32
NumberOfFATs                db 2
NUmberOfRootDirEntries          db 224
NumberOfSectors             dd 2880
MediaDescriptorType         db 0xf0     ;3.5 Inch Double-Sided HD Floppy disk(1.44MB or 2.88MB) should work with single-sided ones as well, maybe even 5.25 inch diskettes
SectorsPerFAT               db 9
SectorsPerTrack             db 18
NumberOfSides               db 2
HiddenSectors               db 0
LargeSectorCount            db 0

;EBPB

DriveNumber             db 0x00 ;Floppy Disk
                    db 0    ;Reserved
Signature               db 0x29
VolumeID                db 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
VolumeLabel             db "POSBOOTDSK "
SystemIdentifier            db "FAT12   "

mbrcodestart:

mov bx, POSBL_WelcomeString
call print16
call read16

mov ah, 0x0e
mov al, [ExtendedSpace]
int 0x10


jmp ExtendedSpace

POSBL_WelcomeString:
    db "PlanetOS BootLoader (POSBL) v0.1 (limited compatability)",0

print16:
    mov ah, 0x0e
    loop:
        mov al, [bx]
        cmp al, byte 0
        je exit
        int 0x10
        inc bx
        jmp loop
    exit:
        ret
    
ExtendedSpace equ 0x7e00

read16:
    mov ah, 0x02
    mov al, 20
    mov bx, ExtendedSpace
    mov ch, 0x00
    mov cl, 0x02
    mov dh, 0x00
    mov dl, 0x00
    int 0x13
    ret


times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

Answer (score 0):

The first instruction executed after `jmp ExtendedSpace` is `db 'H'` i.e. not code

Comment: In that case it's a duplicate of [Assembly (x86):  db 'string',0 does not get executed unless there's a jump instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30561366).  I already voted to close this question as lacking a [mcve], so I can't close it myself  :/ But others can flag as duplicate if they have some minimum rep.

Comment: I agree that it is a bad choice the OP made but it will not pose a problem as that particular encoding 72 happens to correspond to a valid one-byte instruction `dec ax`. Its execution will be harmless.